# Cancatenate many list where elements have the same length

Tags: r

Assume that I have three lists :

```
List1 <- list(c(1,2,3),c('A','B','C','D'),c(0,2))
List2 <- list(c(5,6,7),c('AA','BB','CC','DD'),c(1,5))
List3 <- list(c(1,1,1),c('F','G','H','E'),c(0,6))
```

The needed result should be a list as:

```
List
[[1]]
1 5 1
2 6 1
3 7 1

[[2]]
'A' 'AA' 'F'
'B' 'BB' 'G'
'C' 'CC' 'H'
'D' 'DD' 'E'

[[3]]
0 2
1 5
0 6
```

I tried using cbind(List1 ,List2,List3), But it doesn't give the needed result.

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: I think based on the pattern showed, the last list element in expected should be transpose of what you showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
mapply(cbind, List1, List2, List3)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    2    6    1
[3,]    3    7    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "AA" "F" 
[2,] "B"  "BB" "G" 
[3,] "C"  "CC" "H" 
[4,] "D"  "DD" "E" 

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    2    5    6
```

Comment: If there are many `list` elements, you could do `do.call(mapply, c(FUN = cbind, mget(paste0("List", 1:3))))`

Answer (score 1):

We can the objects named as `List` followed by numbers in a `list`, `transpose` (from `purrr`) it and convert it to a `tibble` or `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(paste0("List", 1:3)) %>% 
     transpose %>% 
     map(as_tibble)
```